# Hazelcast without Split-Brain Recovery (merge)

Tags: caching, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I'm experimenting Hazelcast, but in scenario of split brain, it automatically try to merge the cluster with PutIfAbsentMergePolicy. Is there any way to ignore the merge policy and just keep working with a inconsistent cluster? I want my app to be 100% available all the time and not try to merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [merge policy](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/network-partitioning/split-brain-recovery.html#merge-policies) from the existing ones or write your custom one. However, I don't think you can avoid merging the cluster back after the split brain.

Comment: yeah, I thought this, but a member from hazelcast team suggest to use this config https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/network-partitioning/split-brain-protection.html with split-brain disabled. I'm still trying to do this.